# How to focus excel on a VM

Tags: java, .net, excel, vba, salesforce

I am having problems reauthenticating to a salesforce powerquery in Excel.

I am attempting to automate a few reports containing a large quantity of data.  This data is pulled from salesforce into excel using power query.  The issue I am having is that I need to re authenticate after approximately 1 hour.  There is an authentication box that pops up in excel, that I can use a Single Sign on application to enter my credentials and have me reconnected.  The issue I am having, is that if my Excel workbook is launched with a script or windows task scheduler, the Excel window is not in focus, and my SSO application can not take over.  I have tried setting focus using a simple C# application that successfully brings it to the foreground, however it does not set focus as though a human clicked on the app.

This all takes place on a VM that is dedicated to setting up these reports.  Does anyone have any insight on how I can either A) Set focus to the window to allow my SSO to take over, or B) Alternative ways to re authenticate when excel prompts for it?  For data security, the requirement for 1 hour authentication can not be removed.

I have VBA, Java, C#, VB, and powershell in my toolbox to use to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you try to have your excel spreadsheet always on top of other windows? You can try this with the excel macros. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2030-keep-excel-window-on-top.html

Comment: If you have an instance of the Excel `Application`, you can get the `hWnd` handle of its main window - from there you're one p/invoke (Win32) call away from focusing it. Other than that, unattended execution of any Office desktop application isn't a supported, nor a recommended scenario - consider pulling the SF data into an actual database instead, and PQ connecting to the database (SF auth makes no difference then)

Comment: I have tried, however bringing it to the top most window does not seem to be setting focus the same as a human clicking inside the excel window.